# Getting the right file permissions when building packages in /usr/local/src

Tags: linux, debian, permissions, tar

As far as I understand, when you build a package *foo* located in `/usr/local/src` you shouldn't need to be root. However, when I extract the package and try to run the build script it fails because it doesn't have permissions to create new files in `/usr/local/src/foo`:

```
$ pwd
/usr/local/src
$ ls -ld .
drwxrwsr-x 5 root staff 4096 May 16 20:36 .
$ ls -l foo.tar.gz 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root staff 206574 May 16 20:35 foo.tar.gz
$ sudo tar xf foo.tar.gz
$ ls -ld foo
drwxr-sr-x 7 root staff 4096 May 16 20:36 foo/
```

What is the correct way to solve this problem? Should I add myself to the group *staff* and run `sudo chmod g+w foo`?

Comment: Why do you use `sudo` to extract the sources? If you're a member of `staff`, that should not be needed and would just create root-owned files and directories. Also, you can build software anywhere, for example in your home directory.

Comment: @Kusalananda You are right; adding oneself to the group *staff* solves the problem. If you turn your comment into an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extraction of the archive as root creates a root-owned directory hierarchy, which you can't create files in.

I would suggest adding yourself to the `staff` group so that you can extract the sources without `sudo`.

Or, which is what I would personally do, build the software elsewhere, for example in a subdirectory of `$HOME`. This should be possible to do when building virtually any software.

Comment: I like doing things the standard way unless I find a better approach. The nice thing about building and installing a package in the `/usr/local` tree is that you don't need to specify a `--prefix`. When you build a package in `$HOME`, do you also install it in `$HOME`?

Comment: @AugustKarlstrom The default installation prefix for GNU software is always the same, regardless of where you build the code.

Comment: Yes, but if a package is installed in `/usr/local`, it's easier to find its source if it's put in `/usr/local/src`. For me it makes sense to have both the source and the installation under a common path (`/usr/local`).

Comment: @AugustKarlstrom Sure. Where an administrator keeps source code is their own preference.